# Is it possible to style a (must be dropdown list/select option, not checkbox/radio button) options to box/div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is the aspect i want to make, each box represent each option

[image]

```
<label for="product">Choose:</label>

    <select name="product" id="product">
      <option value="70A">Volvo</option>
      <option value="70B">Saab</option>
      <option value="70C">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="75A">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: yes, it is possible to do that - by the way, those boxes are not square

Comment: Yep, using css just set the width then use aspect-ratio to 1/1 which makes it square. You'll need to add some code though to make your problem reproducible so people can help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: adam i didn't find any similar  code up to now which can make it, so i can't provide source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make divs with each() from all your select options.

Then you get the click on them and change the value of your hidden select.

Edit : i commented my code.

```js
// lets make divs options for the select
customSelect("selectOne", "customSelectOne", 1);
customSelect("selectTwo", "customSelectTwo", 0);

// get the click for each options created
$(document).on("click",".selectOption", function (event) {
  // first, we remove class for each option div
  $(this).parent("div:first").find('.selectOption').removeClass('checked');

  const getOptionID = $(this).data('optionid'); // get value of data optionid
  $(this).toggleClass('checked'); // add/remove checked class
   // change value of hiddent select
  $(this).parent("div:first").prevAll('select:first').val(getOptionID).change();
});

$('.hideShowSelect').click(function() {
  $('select').toggle();
});

/*
  loop that make reproduce options of your select
  @select : selector of the select
  @div : selector of the div that will contain the divs for each option
  @checked : 1 to make first div checked or 0 to not
*/
function customSelect(select, div, checked) {
  // we loop each option
  $('select[name="' + select + '"] option').each(function(index) {
    // check if need to add checked class if index is equal to 0 and checked equal to 1
    const checkFirstOption = (index === 0 && checked === 1 ? ' checked' : '');
    const optionVal = $(this).val(); // get option value
    
    // create a div for the option with data value with option value
    $('.' + div).append('<div class="selectOption'+ checkFirstOption +'" data-optionid="' + optionVal + '">' + optionVal + '</div>');
  });
}
```

```css
#myform {
  max-width:450px;
  margin-top:25px;
}

#myform select {
  display:none;
}

#myform .selectOption {
  color:#141414;
  cursor:pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #bebebe;
  padding:15px 17.5px;
  border-radius:2.5px;
  margin:5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

#myform .selectOption.checked {
  border: 1px solid #111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <select name="selectOne">
    <option value="70A">70A</option>
    <option value="70B">70B</option>
    <option value="70C">70C</option>
    <option value="75A">75A</option>
    <option value="75B">75B</option>
    <option value="75C">75C</option>
  </select>
  <div class="customSelectOne"></div>
  
  <select name="selectTwo">
    <option value="80B">80B</option>
    <option value="80C">80C</option>
    <option value="80D">80D</option>
    <option value="85B">85B</option>
    <option value="85C">85C</option>
    <option value="85D">85D</option>
  </select> 
  <div class="customSelectTwo"></div>
</form>

<p><a href="#" class="hideShowSelect">Hide / show select</a></p>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, each time only one option can be selected.

Comment: What you mean by each time ?

Comment: just like radio button, but not multi selection, but i need to use dropdown list

Comment: dropdown list doesn't mean multi select - you need to be clear in your questions @hkguile

Comment: i've make the question more clear, it must be dropdown list/select option, but not radio button, or checkbox. thanks

Comment: @hkguile check it plz

Comment: I have something very similar to this, but have a question:
In my code, the original selectOne element dynamically creates a list of options in the selectTwo select box. Is there a way of invoking the code again once the first select option has been chosen, in order to display the new options in selectTwo as divs?

Comment: Make a new question and then ill come to try to answer it @Gary